# OAuth token request via username and password in python

Tags: rest-api, oauth2

All this while it was working and not sure what have changed. The point of failure is within this code block

```
import urllib2

    url = 'https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token'
    data = '&grant_type=password&client_id='+CLIENT_ID+'&client_secret='+CLIENT_SECRET+'&username='+username+'&password='+password
    headers = {'X-PrettyPrint' : '1'}

    req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
    res = urllib2.urlopen(req) #this is where it fails!
```

Below is the console error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 397, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 510, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 435, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 518, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

Not sure what have changed in Salesforce, that is not updated in the docs yet.

Comment: Did you reset the integration user's password and update your password however you are storing? If you did the security token may have changed which can cause Bad request

Comment: I have tried with different users with no success. Will the client id and client secret from the connected app, expire?

Comment: In your password do you append security token along with the password?

Comment: We dont use security token, it have been disabled... and this have been working all this time. At this point, i haven't tried with a new client id and client secret, i have tried all other combinations. Does this client id and client secret expire?

Comment: AFAIK client Id and secrets do not expire. Did you guys by any chance enable mydomain in your org? have you allowed login from test.salesforce.com

Comment: Look into the logs. I am now seeing in the "login history" of the user that says the status as "failed: login over insecure channel" .... it is using the tls 1.0

Comment: aha that might be the issue. salesforce recently decommissioned tls 1.0 https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000221207&type=1. as per the doc : API (inbound) Integrations 
API Integrations are interfaces or applications–including mobile apps and desktop clients–that are separate from Salesforce, but use Salesforce data. If you have any API Integrations, please ensure that the TLS 1.1 and/or TLS 1.2 encryption protocols are enabled in those integrations.

Comment: yes - this seems to be the issue. a local test by upgrading the python to 2.7.13 seems to connect okay (to use the SSLContext). But there is still an uncertainty as to why the log is saying that i was using TLS2 and then it started showing TLS1.

Comment: i am not  a big expert when it comes to how the servers/browsers manage the TLS versions. Assuming the endpoint was being accessed through different servers/browsers

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by using the `SSLContext` as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22657498/i-want-to-choose-the-transport-layer-security-protocol-in-urllib2). And to use this, i had to upgrade to python v2.7.13 although it started supporting from v2.7.9

So now, it looks like

```
import urllib2
import ssl 

ctx = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
url = 'https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token'
data = '&grant_type=password&client_id='+CLIENT_ID+'&client_secret='+CLIENT_SECRET+'&username='+username+'&password='+password
headers = {'X-PrettyPrint' : '1'}

req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
res = urllib2.urlopen(req, context=ctx)
```